# Enforce uniqueness of an m:n relation as an additional foreign key with Prisma schema

Tags: orm, foreign-keys, prisma

I have a many to many relation in Prisma that looks like the following :

```
model User {
  id                Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  calendars         CalendarsOnUsers[]
}

model Calendar {
  id      Int     @id @default(autoincrement())
  calendarType    String
  users           CalendarsOnUsers[]
  calendarEvents  CalendarEventsOnCalendars[]
}

model CalendarsOnUsers {
  user                      User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId                    Int
  calendar                  Calendar @relation(fields: [calendarId], references: [id])
  calendarId                Int     

  @@id([userId, calendarId])
}
```

A user can have multiple calendars, and a calendar can be attributed to multiple users (for example, a company event calendar or a team calendar).

The above model is a basic many to many relation that works, but I want to enforce uniqueness of two fields compounded : `calendarType` and `userId`. For example, a user can have multiple calendars with calendarType `Business`, `Personal`, `Holiday`. However I want it such that one user cannot have two of the same `calendarType`; one user shouldn't be able to have two `Business` calendars.

How can I enforce this uniqueness with Prisma?

Answer (score 0):

I thought about it a bit more and I kept thinking about how to enforce the relation on the `CalendarOnUsers` table when I should have stopped to think about what table should actually own the relation, or rather how this uniqueness should be enforced.

I was trying to enforce a PK without just using a PK, and had a meaningless `calendarId` that didn't help me identify the calendar object the way I wanted. So I simply replaced `calendarId` with a compound id with `userId` and `calendarType` to create a schema like the following :

```
model User {
  id                Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  calendars         CalendarsOnUsers[]
  calendarsCreated  Calendar[]
}

model Calendar {
  calendarType          String
  users                 CalendarsOnUsers[]
  calendarEvents        CalendarEventsOnCalendars[]
  calendarOwnerId       Int       
  calendarOwner         User      @relation(fields: [calendarOwnerId], references: [id])

  @@id([calendarOwnerId, calendarType])
} 

model CalendarsOnUsers {
  calendarAttributedTo      User     @relation(fields: [calendarAttributedToId], references: [id])
  calendarAttributedToId    Int
  calendar                  Calendar @relation(fields: [calendarType, calendarOwnerId], references: [calendarType, calendarOwnerId])
  calendarType              String
  calendarOwnerId           Int

  @@unique([calendarOwnerId, calendarType])
  @@id([calendarAttributedToId, calendarType, calendarOwnerId])
}
```

This creates two relations where a User is a *creator* of a calendar and can also be *attributed* a calendar.